# Dynamically added stylesheet not showing up in IE Developer Tools

Tags: css, internet-explorer, debugging

I'm working on a cross-browser bookmarklet where I need to inject my own style sheet into the page as well as various divs, etc. I've got it working everywhere but IE so am now attempting to debug some of the styling issues there.

I'm adding my css to the document after a user clicks my bookmarklet as follows:

```
if (document.createStyleSheet){
    document.createStyleSheet("http://mydomain.com/css/mystyle.css");
} else {
    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mydomain.com/css/mystyle.css" type="text/css" />');
}
```

The file is being fetched and applied to divs, etc. I create on the page, however when I inspect the element in IE 9 Developer Tools it does not show me ANY properties from the stylesheet I added dynamically, only those in the style="{}" attr.

Also, mystyle.css does not show up in the dropdown on the CSS tab, yet it does have a corresponding  element in the head and styles in it are being applied to the dom correctly.

Any thoughts on how to force the dev tools to recognize my new sheet? It is infuriating to attempt to debug css w/o being able to manipulate it in-browser directly.

Answer (score 4):

Did you click the refresh button in developer tools?  It doesn't refresh the page, it reloads the dom from the current page.

Comment: Yep. It shows the newly-added <link href="mystyle.css"..> element in the head, and I can see the new divs I've added rendered appropriately, however in the Dev Tools their Style and Trace Style tabs simply show "display:block" and the like; none of the styles from mystyle.css are shown.

Comment: Well, developer tools has a number of situation where it doesn't "see" things.  There's not much you can do about it, other than use FF or Chrome to debug the problem.  If it's an IE specific problem, then i would suggest temporarily adding the stylesheet statically rather than dynamically to debug the problem.

Comment: I was afraid of that :(. It is an IE-specific issue (well, a number of them) and it being a bookmarklet, I'm injecting it into any arbitrary page so can't simply add it statically short of creating a local copy of a target page for debugging purposes, which is probably what I'll do. Oh well. Thanks for the thoughts.

Comment: @MystereMan - good suggestion.  I have a test page and that's exactly what I did, add the <link> to the dynamic stylesheet right to the test page.  Very helpful, thanks.